# How do i add multer middleware to my express controller NOT in the router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, multer

This is the format I use to write controllers and routes in Express

controller

```
exports.postBlog = async (req, res, next) => {...}
```

routes

```
router.route("/post").post(onlyAdmin, postBlog);
```

*onlyAdmin is a protection middleware

I want to add the multer method below in the controller just before the async (req, res, next) so that the uploading logic is handled by the controller not the router

```
upload.single("image")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call multer upload middleware from the controller:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer().single('image');

exports.postBlog = async (req, res, next) => {

     upload(req, res, function (err) {
        //...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since route handlers accept arrays too, you can to this:

```
exports.postBlog = [
  upload.single("image"),
  async (req, res, next) => {...}
];
```